# Set route's allowed methods with annotation when using FOSRestBundle

Tags: php, symfony, fosrestbundle

I'm wondering if there's an easy way to alter allowed methods for routes generated via FOSRestBundle using `type: rest` in `routing.yml`:

For example I have:

```
public function regularAction()
{
}
```

which is transformed into:

```
Name                             Method     Scheme   Host   Path
-------------------------------- ---------- -------- ------ -----------------------
pria_core_regular                GET        ANY      ANY    /regular.{_format}
```

I can change the path generated with `FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations\Route\Method` annotation:

```
/**
 * @Route("/test-regular")
 */
public function regularAction()
{
}
```

Then the route is as I expected:

```
Name                             Method     Scheme   Host   Path
-------------------------------- ---------- -------- ------ -----------------------
pria_core_regular                GET        ANY      ANY    /test-regular.{_format}
```

However I can't do the same with overriding allowed methods. For example:

```
@Method({"GET", "POST"})
```

Using `@Method` has no effect. Is this intentionally disabled by FOSRestBundle?

Comment: Hi Martin, did you get anything? I want the same!

Answer (score 0):

In order to set the request methods, please implement your routes like this:

```
// Get Action
public function getRegular() {}

// Post Action 
public function postRegular() {}
```

---

Edit: Apologies, I didn't understand the question 100%, prepending your controller method with get/post etc will set the methods, please see [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSRestBundle/6-automatic-route-generation_multiple-restful-controllers.html#define-child-resource-controller)

Comment: I don't want to hardcode route paths, that's FOS's job, I just want to change the methods.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't very specific, I wanted to just change methods, without copy&pasting paths. Using @`Get`, `@Post`, etc. requires you to always specify full path which is what I don't want.